# Adding all the numbers from a list together(not summing). Python 3.3.2

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

say that I have this list:

```
alist = [2, 0, 1]
```

How would I make a string named "hahaha" for example equal to 201 ? Not 5 (sum).
Would I need to something like "

```
for number in alist .....
```

thanks !

Comment: Just for printing it as `201` you can do: `print (*alist, sep='')`

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`''.join()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) in conjunction with [`map()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):

```
>>> alist = [2, 0, 1]
>>> ''.join(map(str, alist))
'201'
```

Comment: ```imap``` doesn't create intermediate list :P

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
hahaha = ''.join([str(num) for num in alist])
print hahaha  # '201'
```

---

To explain what's going on:

The portion `[str(num) for num in alist]` is called a "list comprehension" -- it's like a very condensed `for-loop` that transforms one list into another list.  In this case, it turns `[2, 0, 1]` into `['2', '0', '1']`.

(We could, of course, write this as a for-loop instead of as a list comprehension, but it take more lines of code, and would be a little tedious to type)

The section portion `''.join(list)` takes a list of strings, and sticks them all together with the empty string as the separating character.  If I were to do `'+'.join([str(num) for num in alist])`, the output would be `'2+0+1'` instead.

So, the line can be thought of as a series of transformations that slowly converts the initial list into a string.

```
[2, 0, 1] -> ['2', '0', '1'] -> '201'
```

---

We can also wrap this whole process into a function, like so:

```
def make_str(list):
    return ''.join([str(num) for num in list])

print make_str([4, 3, 2, 9])  # '4329'
print make_str([9, 0, 0, 9])  # '9009'
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
>>> alist = [2, 0, 1]
>>> "".join(str(i) for i in alist)
'201'
```

The code inside `join()` method is a [generator expression](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/).

Comment: [For `str.join` a genexp is both slower and less efficient than LC.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/846892)

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary this is useful information, but do you have some links explaining? I can test it but it would be nice to understand why is it so

Comment: @RomanPekar I've updated my  comment with a link.

Comment: @Ashwini Chaudhary You are right. It's even in the docs http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#basic-examples , and I checked it for both Python2.7 and 3.2, however, generator expressions may be more efficient in other settings.

Answer (score 1):

The string join function needs a list of strings.

```
''.join([str(i) for i in alist])
```