# How can I remove these parenthesis in the output?

Tags: python

This is probably a silly question but I don't really know much about Python yet. I'm writing this code that is suppose to take the input for values of X and the input for values of Y, write them in files and print them on the screen (later on I'll plot them with matplotlib). But I'm getting on my outputs two parenthesis that I didn't want them to be there. Here's the code (I'm programming on Ubuntu with Python 3.4):

```
xcoord = open("x.dat","w")
xinput = input('Enter with the values for x separeted by coma (ex: 10,25,67):')
xcoord.write(str(xinput))
xcoord.close()
ycoord = open("y.dat","w")
yinput = input('Enter with the values for y separeted by coma (ex: 10,25,67):')
ycoord.write(str(yinput))
ycoord.close()

xcoord = open("x.dat","r")
listax = xcoord.read().split(',')
ycoord = open("y.dat","r")
listay = ycoord.read().split(',')
print listax
print listay
```

The output I'm getting in the files is something like (10, 20, 30) and the output I'm getting on the screen is something like ['(10','20','30)']. How can I get rid of these parenthesis?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding all the numbers from a list together(not summing). Python 3.3.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18816813/adding-all-the-numbers-from-a-list-togethernot-summing-python-3-3-2)

Comment: I suspect you're using Python 2, not Python 3.  (The code you post is not valid in Python 3.) In that case, if you replace `input` with `raw_input`, that will avoid the parentheses being created in the first place.  If you *are* using Python 3, then there shouldn't be any parentheses in your output, and you don't need to convert to `str` before in your `write` method calls.

Comment: wow you are right, my bad. I'm really new to python programming. I checked and my ubuntu came with python 2.7 installed, not 3.4. Thanks for the heads up, i'll look around to understand the difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do with [`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip):

```
>>> '(10, 20, 30)'.strip('()')
'10, 20, 30'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remove first and last character on printing:

```
print listax[1:-1]
```